# lineWidth on both sides of chart

Tags: highcharts

When I create a chart, I can place a nice line on the right side of the chart like so:

```
yAxis: [{
    height: '65%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
}, {
    top: '75%',
    height: '25%',
    offset: 0,
    lineWidth: 2
}]
```

[image: Line on right]

I have been asked to add an additional line on the left of the chart, but I don't see a built-in way to do that in the [API docs](http://api.highcharts.com/highstock).  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way could be to add y axes on left side that will be `linkedTo` main y axes.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/86zm6cav/

```
      yAxis: [{
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'OHLC'
            },
            height: '60%',
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            labels: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -3
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Volume'
            },
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            offset: 0,
            lineWidth: 2
        }, {
            opposite: false,
            height: '60%',
            linkedTo: 0,
            lineWidth: 2,
            offset: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }, {
            opposite: false,
            top: '65%',
            height: '35%',
            linkedTo: 1,
            lineWidth: 2,
            offset: 0,
            labels: {
                enabled: false
            }
        }],
```

Other option is to use renderer and create a custom path(s).

API reference for renderer: http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts#Renderer.path